# scala 22 param's and more args *

Tags: scala

We know that scala does not support more than 22 params, but if i write this

```
 def echo(args: String*) = for (arg <- args) println(arg)
```

we can use more than 22 params to call this function like this.

```
echo("1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1")
```

But I think this is an array. So, it can do that and i tried this

```
val a = Array[String]("1","2","3");echo(a)
```

This code must be wrong, so here's my first question, why is this happening?
and, if i try to write this

```
echo(a : _*)
```

It's right,the second question is, what does this sign means '_*'? I can't use this code in other ways like in for(). So, is echo(a : _ *) is a right code?

Comment: The limitation on 22 params is on the number of parameters for a case class. I think this limitation has been fixed with newer version of Scala (https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7296)

Answer (score 4):

The *echo* function is defined to take a variable number of string arguments. This is really only syntactic sugar; the compiler will insert the necessary instructions to wrap the arguments in an array and then pass the array. So the function will actually only receive a single argument at runtime.

The reason you can't pass the array directly is that there is no additional compiler logic to automagically figure out that the string arguments are already wrapped. The function declaration indicates that zero or more strings are expected, the parameter is actually an array, and a compiler error results.

The : _* notation is additional syntactic sugar to account for this problem; by using this syntax you indicate to the compiler that you are intentionally passing an array instead of the variable number of string parameters.